# openxlsx having problems with detect dates

Tags: r, excel

I'm using the package `openxlsx` to open a .xlsx file into `R`. This is a basic example of the data I'm trying to read:

[image]

This is the code I use to read the excel:

`read.xlsx("F:/Test.xlsx",colNames = T,detectDates = T)`

but i get the following error:

```
Error in read.xlsx.default("F:/Test.xlsx", colNames = T, detectDates = T) : 
  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 8) > this->size() (which is 2)
```

If I delete the first row of the excel I keep getting the same error. And it's really wired because the last time I run the script (2 weeks ago) the Excel was in the same format and I didn't get this error and I haven't updated R or Rstudio or the package.

Comment: (1) What sort of date is `19/20/2017`?, (2) R and openxlsx are going to be looking to make each column a single type of data. I'm not sure how you expect that to play out here.

Comment: @joran 1) I made a mistake in the example but change it to `09/20/2017` (which is a date) and the same error happens. 2) character, that's what I use to get the I convert all the data to the corresponding format. It is just the excel structure I HAVE to work with

Comment: Then you're never going to succeed in reading columns as dates. You'll have to read everything as characters and then re-organize everything in R.

Comment: @joran yes but when I first wrote the code if I didn't add the `detectDates=T` it would convert all the dates into numbers and I didn't want that, and still don't

Comment: Yeah, that's Excel being a pain. You'll need to convert all the column to Text _in Excel_.

Comment: @joran not posible in my real data and I don't have to do that the first time I wrote the code and the 10 time I have read it since today. I need it to keep working as I had but I can't understand what's happening because I didn't change anything since last time I run it

Comment: The problem isn't the code. Whatever was happening in the past it was _not_ creating a data frame with columns of mixed types. So it was either reading the dates as characters or converting them to integers. If something changed, it will be in the formatting of the Excel file.

Comment: @joran I'll check a backup of that file and see if the format change anyway its really wired thanks any way

Comment: Weird and unexpected is **normal** for Excel files, particularly when it comes to dates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I changed on excel the format date from: 09/20/2017 to 09/20/17 and read.xlsx worked.

Comment: Nice it worked for you but I can't change the date format in excel, everyone have the same format in my company

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to solve this issue might be to read your data without `detectDates=TRUE` and once you have it in your R- workspace, accordingly convert those columns that include dates (which will be read as doubles) using `xlsx` function: `convertToDate`.

Comment: I ended up using ` detectDates=False` so it reads as number and then converting it to date. But its just a work around, no a solution to the problem

Comment: You can also convert from number to date using the command:
`df$date <- as.Date(df$date, origin = "1899-12-30")`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and found that calling loadWorkbook first and passing the workbook to read.xlsx instead of the filename resolves this error.

For this example do:

```
wb = loadworkbook("F:/Test.xlsx")
read.xlsx(xlsxFile=wb,sheet=1,colNames = T,detectDates = T)
```