# openxlsx function read.xlsx fails to correctly read dates in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a `.xlsx` file in R, using the `openxlsx` package. Unfortunately, the spreadsheet has some strange formatting in the date column, which is in the format "Month/Day/Year", e.g. `9/21/2014`. (Excel recognises this as a date format). When importing with `read.xlsx`, the month and day are missed off, leaving only the year as a numeric column. I suspect it is something to do with the `/` character.

```
df <- read.xlsx("The File.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet 1")

head(df)
  Number       Type         Other.Type     Date
    1           902             611        2014     
    2           902             611        2014   
    3           902             611        2014    
    4           795             966        2014 
 ...
```

I've tried including the `detectDates = TRUE` argument, but that just gives `NAs`.

I can't edit the spreadsheet as the data belongs to someone else and I have just been given access to it. Is there an equivalent of the `colClasses` argument from the `xlsx` package, or any other way of getting the data into R?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you may have a similar problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762480/openxlsx-having-problems-with-detect-dates)

Comment: @KenHBS, yes looks like the same issue (although all my data are in single columns of the same type). But similarly, I can't change the input file, only edit it once in R.

Comment: Perhaps you could transform the xlsx to some other format first? Csv or so

Comment: See if the [janitor package helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804353/r-importing-xlsx-file-with-date-column).

Comment: @KenHBS, yes, that does resolve it. I was hoping to avoid that sort of workaround because there are multiple sheets in the file, but needs must! And thanks for the tip @Anonymous, the `janitor` package looks really useful.

Comment: That does not work with the `readxl` package ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes it looks like it has read it ok, even formatted it into `Y-M-D`. I was hoping to avoid changing packages. Are there any issues with `readxl` that would discourage me from switching to `openxlsx` full time? (e.g. like the `xlsx` dependency on Java)

Comment: There's no issue with `readxl` AFAIK. A nice feature is the possibility to read a column with different types within it (read as a list). And it is fast. `openxlsx` is a great package to *write* Excel files (allowing styling, inclusion of images, comments...). `readxl` is the best to *read* Excel files. Moreover `readxl` is under intensive maintenance; if you find a bug, report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is just for completeness, in case anyone else ends up here with a similar problem. All thanks due to @StéphaneLaurent, who provided the suggestion in the comments.

Switching to the `readxl` package resolved the problems. Note be sure to check the the help file for the `read_xlsx` call; particularly for the `col_types` argument. This package will attempt to set each vector's data type on import, and if there are any inconsistencies it will produce warnings such as

```
In read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits,  ... :
Expecting numeric in F1107 / R1107C6: got '?'
```

These are not a serious issue, so don't be put off using the package. Thanks, Stéphane!

---

**EDIT ~ 1 week later**

After using `readxl` in another script with different data, I have switched back to using `openxlsx` as my basic go-to package. Although `readxl` worked well as a workaround for my original issue, the number of `warnings()` it throws up is really irritating. In this second case, it was becoming unusable; each time I ran a line of code (whether `readxl` was involved or not), it would trigger warnings about e.g. `Unknown or uninitialised column`. This was only resolved by closing down the R session and starting again. I'm sure it is only because I'm making a small mistake with `readxl`, but unless I'm faced with the same situation as above with mis-formatted dates, I will stick with `openxlsx`, which I have generally found straightforward to use.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me after changing the format in excel to:  date "2012-03-14"

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "The File.xlsx", sheet = "sheet 1" , detectDates = TRUE)
```